# How to convert 00:00:23 to 00:23 using PHP gmdate function

Tags: php

I have this code to show video duration in my app.

```
$duration = 23; // seconds
$duration = gmdate("H:i:s", $duration);
```

The above code outputs 00:00:23 but hours field is not required since it is just 23 seconds, I would like it to show 00:23 seconds, and if the video length is more than hour for example, it should show 01:24:19

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$duration = gmdate($duration >= 3600 ? 'H:i:s' : 'i:s', $duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The above code outputs 00:00:23 but hours field is not required since it is just 23 seconds, I would like it to show 00:23 seconds, and if the video length is more than hour for example, it should show 01:24:19

How about a simple if?

```
<?php
$duration = $duration >= ( 60 * 60 ) ? gmdate( 'H:i:s', $duration ) : gmdate( 'i:s', $duration );
echo $duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$duration = gmdate( ($duration >= 3600 ? "H:i:s" : "i:s"), $duration);
```